# Minimum total euclidean difference between two list of coordinates

Tags: python, matching, least-squares

For two lists with equal length, I'm trying to find the minimum total difference between the coordinates of each list. For example two lists are

```
l1 = [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)]
l2 = [(x4,y4),(x5,y5),(x6,y6)]
```

and the euclidean distance would be calculated by simply

```
r = sqrt((x1-x4)^2 + (y1-y4)^2)
```

and this would need to be done with all coordinates and all matches to find the optimal solution. My current thought is complexity of N! by x1,y1 comparing with all in l2, x2,y2 with the two left over and the last match with the last one. Is this the most optimal way or is there something better.

Comment: Why is it O(N!)? You're computing the distance between each element in `l1` to each element in `l2`, that's O(N²)

Comment: Because once first element in list 1 matches with an element in list 2, no other elements in list 1 can match with that element in list 2.

Comment: So, the first element will compare N values, the second element will compare N-1 values, until the last element, which will have only 1 value. The total number of distances computed (and compared) is `N+(N-1)+(N-2)+ ... + 2 + 1`. This is **not N!**. It is O(N²).

Comment: Ah crap ok so that idea goes out the door. Is there a solution that is lower than O(N^2)?

Comment: Would you please share your code?

Comment: Haven't got anything solid yet, discussing ideas. Also surely if every item in l1 is compared to l2, that would be complexity O(N^N)?

Comment: You suspected O(N!) but you react negatively to O(N^2)? O(N!) is fantastically worse than O(N^2).

Also, O(N^N) is in fact O(N!), due to [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), and no, it's O(N^2), which is to say O(N*N).